# Replace a particular word in a sentence with another word in php

Tags: php

```
if($_GET["op"]=="replace"){
            $str=$_GET["input"];
            $pos=$_GET["input2"];
            $apos=explode(',',$pos);
            echo"After replaced:".str_replace($apos[0],$apos[1],$str);
}
```

when I give an input sentence `hi this is a good day`
and give word to be replaced, as `is`.
let the other word to be replaced with is `not`.

Then the output will be: `hi thnot not good day`.

How can make the output be `hi this not good day`

Comment: you would have to use a regular expression to detect whether or not the word is part of another word or using just string functions, look for each instance of your search word and check the previous/next character to see if it is part of another word before replacing one at a time.

Comment: if the input is `hi this...` why are you exploding on `,`? There are no `,` on your input.

Comment: $str contains the sentence. im reading word to be replaced with and replacing word to $pos. eg $pos will have "is,not"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
preg_replace("/\b(is)\b/", "not", $input_lines);
```

[Check the code](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/css)

```
if($_GET["op"]=="replace"){
    $str=$_GET["input"];
    $pos=$_GET["input2"];
    $apos=explode(',',$pos);
    echo"After replaced:".preg_replace("/\b(".$apos[0].")\b/", $apos[1], $str)
}
```

Comment: Good catch that the expected output string doesn't include ` a `, but I'm assuming that was a mistake. If you are just doing a straight string match, you don't need to preg_replace as str_replace will do exactly the same thing with less overhead. Ideally you would detect word boundary or start/end of the string.

Comment: im using variable to store words to be replaced with and replace. i tried preg_replace("/ $apos[0]  /",$apos[1],$str); giving space between "/_$pos[0]_/". but it didnt work.

Comment: Try this `"/(".$apos[0].")/"`. What is the `$_GET["input2"]`?

Comment: $_GET["input2"] ,it is used to read the inputs from user ie the word to be replaced and replaced with .

Comment: Ok now I understood what happening. I'll fix that!

Comment: @bangBang Fixed `preg_replace("/\b(".$apos[0].")\b/", $apos[1], $str)`, adding `\b` mean that you want to match the entire word.